# Multiple transaction calls made from Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a situation where lets say I have two services

```
AccountService 
CustomerService
```

Both annotated with `@Transactional` with some `createXXX()` methods.

Now from my `AccountController` lets say I have a method where I would first call `createAccount()` and once I get back the Account-ID from `createAccount()` I may then call `createCustomer()` (To create a Customer and also update Account-ID from `Account` on the `Customer`)

If for some reason `createCustomer()` fails I will be left with a polluted state where `Account` has already been persisted but no `Customer` created.

Should I resolve this with a `TransactionSynchronizationManager` OR how should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Spring transaction use REQUIRES propagation level by default (see org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional#propagation). It means, Spring will not create a new transaction unless there is an existing one. Use this feature: you can either annotate controller's method with `@Transactional` or create a new service that will trigger the top-level transaction. The idea is that as soon as you created one transaction, service calls will not create new ones. As a result, you have just one transaction that can either successfully commit or fail.

Comment: Yes I understand this could be resolved by adding @Transactional at the Controller method. But I dont think this is recommended as I havent seen any example like this. So is the only solution being creating some redundant service like AccountCustomerService with a method createAccountAndThenCustomer() and annotate this with @Transactional?

Comment: @FakirTrappedInCode yes, exactly: you need some kind of an entry point that will create a transaction.